# Как установить библиотеку SciPy на Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, установка

Как то не очень понятно, как можно установить библиотеку ScyPy в операционной системе Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Обновление:** [собранные wheels для Windows](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/5461) доступны для scipy-1.0+ на [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy), то есть стандартную команду для установки можно использовать:

```
T:\> pip install scipy
```

---

<sup>старая версия ответа:</sup>

1. Заходим на https://scipy.org
2. Нажимаем кнопку Install
3. [Читаем инструкцию для Windows.](https://scipy.org/install.html)

Инструкция рекомендует, особенно на Windows, установить не один пакет, а сразу целый набор пакетов (Scientific Python distribution) такой как [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

Если вы хотите индивидуально numpy, scipy пакеты ставить, то инструкция рекомендует бинарные установщики с  [Christoph Gohlke сайта](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), которые доступны в виде бинарных wheel файлов, которые можно напрямую [с помощью `pip` (c версией 8+) поставить](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels):

```
T:\> pip install numpy‑1.12.0b1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
T:\> pip install scipy‑0.18.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Если у вас 64-битная Windows используйте wheel, которые в имени содержат amd64. Если у вас Python 3.6 стоит, то используйте wheel, который cp36m в названии имеет. Перед установкой [scipy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy), необходимо поставить [numpy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).

Не смешивайте установку *бинарных* wheel файлов (таких как на Christoph Gohlke сайте) и установку через [conda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/).

> Там есть файлы с cp27, cp34, cp35, cp36. Интересно, что это обозначает?

Соглашения для имён wheel описаны в [PEP-427](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-name-convention).

Сами метки описаны в [PEP-425](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/#abi-tag).

Метки существуют, чтобы указать системы, где соответствующие бинарные пакеты должны работать.

cp36m—это [ABI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) метка, которая указывает на CPython реализацию (`sys.implementation.name`), версию 3.6 (`sys.version[:3]`) как я выше упомянул, и `m` буква (`sys.abiflags`) в метке указывает на `--with-pymalloc` опцию см. [PEP-3149](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/).

> И какие нужно выбирать для 32 битной Windows?

Метка платформы определяется `distutils.util.get_platform()` значением [согласно PEP-425](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/#platform-tag).

На Windows возможны три (значения из `help(distutils.util.get_platform)`):

- win-amd64 (64bit Windows на AMD64 (aka x86_64, Intel64, EM64T)
- win-ia64 (64bit Windows на Itanium)
- win32 (все другие)

то есть для 32 битной Windows следует win32 метку выбрать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  Вот еще есть такой вопрос.  Там есть файлы с cp27, cp34, cp35, cp36. Интересно,  что это обозначает?  И какие нужно выбирать для 32 битной Windows?