# Ошибка при установке библиотеки Scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

Что за ошибка?

> Command ""c:\program files\python36-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tok
>   enize;**file**='C:\Users\CD86~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1ls_szon\sci
>   kit-learn\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().r
>   eplace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --
>   record C:\Users\CD86~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-4ulwm_uo-record\install-record.txt
>    --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\U
>   sers\CD86~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-1ls_szon\scikit-learn\

Появляется во время установки библиотеки Scikit-learn.

Comment: Компиляция не удалась с кодом ошибки 1. Судя по всему не хватает инструментов компиляции

Comment: Я бы все-таки рекомендовал установить [дистрибутив Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) и не мучаться. Если все же решите пойти путем Леопольда фон Захер-Мазоха то можно воспользоваться [скомпилированными "колесами" (wheel-files) от  Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) ;-)

Comment: Вы устанавливаете из дистрибутива либу или pip?

Comment: Устанавливал с помощью pip

Comment: @АлексейВоронов, используйте обращение через @. В противном случае Вы рискуете тем, что человек не увидит Ваш коммент.

Comment: @АлексейВоронов Очень странно, как Вы запускаете установку?

Comment: @hedgehogues Запускаю командную строку из папки \Python\Python36-32\Scripts. Далее запускаю установку командой pip3 install scikit-learn.

Comment: @АлексейВоронов Попробуйте запуститься от имени администратора

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Error when installing Python scikit-learn](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42733812/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Питона 3.6 ещё нет официальной сборки scikit-learn для Windows на PyPI, [она скорее всего появится вместе с 0.19 версией](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8460). Из исходников такой пакет как scikit-learn с кучей нетривиальных C зависимостей лучше не ставить на Винде.

Если использование [официального установщика для Питон 3.5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikit-learn/0.18.1) не подходит в вашем случае, то попробуйте [неофициальные binary wheel](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn), рекомендуемые в [инструкции по установке](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#windows) (в этом случае самостоятельно зависимости возможно придётся ставить -- аналогично случаю [Как установить библиотеку SciPy на Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/595129/23044)).

В качестве *несовместимой* альтернативы, можно поставить сборку, которая содержит сразу множество пакетов, такую как [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) (scikit-learn уже [включён](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/scikit-learn)).