# Ошибка при импорте NumPy на Windows: ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'

Tags: python, windows, установка, numpy

Python 3.6.2. Установил numpy через командную строку:
pip install numpy
При попытке импорта получаю ошибку ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'
В папке поиска действительно нет такого файла. Вместо него есть multiarray.cp36-win32.pyd и multiarray_tests.cp36-win32.pyd.
В интернете много упоминаний о такой ошибке, но решения в них не нашел. Пробовал ставить предыдущую версию numpy - такой же результат.
В чем причина ошибки?

UPD. Проблема проявлялась, если использовать IDLE 64-bit, если запускать версию для 32 bit, то такой проблемы нет.
NumPy работает только на 32-разрядных системах?

Comment: Поставьте пакет Anaconda - там Numpy уже предустановлен и все пакеты проверены на совместимость...

Comment: если вы поставили 32-битную версия, она будет 32-битным python работать. Поставите 64-битную, она будет с 64-битным python работать.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как установить библиотеку SciPy на Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/595129/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Такие модули как `numpy`, `scipy`, `pandas`, etc. имеют много и зависимостей. Некоторые из этих зависимостей достаточно нетривиально поставить - особенно на Windows.

Существует отлично зарекомендовавший себя дистрибутив - [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/). Он особенно популярен в среде ученых, data scientist's и тех, кто занимается машинным обучением.

Прелесть данного дистрибутива в том что у него [собственный менеджер пакетов](https://conda.io/docs/) и свой репозиторий модулей.

Многие модули (такие как numpy, scipy, pandas и много других) по умолчанию установлены.

Вот, например, цитата из инструкции по установке SciPy:

> For many users, especially on Windows, the easiest way to begin is to
> download one of these Python distributions, which include all the key
> packages:
>
> - Anaconda: A free distribution of Python with scientific packages. Supports Linux, Windows and Mac.
> - Enthought Canopy: The free and commercial versions include the core scientific packages. Supports Linux, Windows and Mac.
> - Python(x,y): A free distribution including scientific packages, based around the Spyder IDE. Windows only.
> - WinPython: A free distribution including scientific packages. Windows only.
> - Pyzo: A free distribution based on Anaconda and the IEP interactive development environment. Supports Linux, Windows and Mac.